# Trying to implement U256 in rust ink! 4.0

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract

I've implemented `use primitive_types::U256` and now I'm trying to return a `U256` int as a result from one of my functions, but I'm getting the following error: *the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `primitive_types::U256`*, I understand that I need to implement `TypeInfo` in my smart contract but I just don't understand how.

Here is the mentioned function:

```
    #[ink(message)]
    pub fn get_est_price_psp22_to_a01(
        &self,
        psp22_amount_in:Balance
    )   -> Result<U256, TradingPairErrors> {

        let caller = self.env().caller();

        //fetching caller current PSP22 balance
        let caller_current_balance:Balance = PSP22Ref::balance_of(
            &self.panx_contract,
            caller
        );

        let actual_fee:Balance;

        //calculating the actual LP fee
        match self.fee.checked_div(10u128.pow(18)) {
            Some(result) => {
                actual_fee = result;
            }
            None => {
                return Err(TradingPairErrors::Overflow);
            }
        };

        let mut amount_in_with_lp_fees:Balance;

        //reducting the LP fee from the PSP22 amount in
        match psp22_amount_in.checked_mul(100u128 - actual_fee) {
            Some(result) => {
                amount_in_with_lp_fees = result;
            }
            None => {
                return Err(TradingPairErrors::Overflow);
            }
        };

        let tokens_to_validate:Balance = 3500u128 * 10u128.pow(18);

        //validating if caller has more than 3500 PANX to verify if the caller is eligible for the incentive program 
        if caller_current_balance >= tokens_to_validate{

            if self.fee  <= 1400000000000u128 {

                //reducting HALF of the LP fee from PSP22 amount in, if the caller has more than 3500 PANX and the LP fee is less than 1.4%
                match psp22_amount_in.checked_mul(100u128 - (actual_fee / 2u128)) {
                    Some(result) => {
                        amount_in_with_lp_fees = result;
                    }
                    None => {
                        return Err(TradingPairErrors::Overflow);
                    }
                };   
            }

            if self.fee  > 1400000000000u128 {

                //reducting (LP fee - 1) of the LP fee from PSP22 amount in, if the caller has more than 3500 PANX and the LP fee is more than 1.4%
                match psp22_amount_in.checked_mul(100u128 - (actual_fee - 1u128)) {
                    Some(result) => {
                        amount_in_with_lp_fees = result;
                    }
                    None => {
                        return Err(TradingPairErrors::Overflow);
                    }
                };  
            }

        }

         
        let a0_amount_out = self.casted_div(amount_in_with_lp_fees * self.get_a0_balance(),(self.get_psp22_balance() * 100u128) + amount_in_with_lp_fees);
        
        //calculating the final A0 amount to transfer to the caller.
        //match (amount_in_with_lp_fees * self.get_a0_balance()).checked_div((self.get_psp22_balance() * 100u128) + amount_in_with_lp_fees) {
        //    Some(result) => {
        //        a0_amount_out = result;
        //    }
        //    None => {
        //        return Err(TradingPairErrors::Overflow);
        //    }
        //};

        Ok(a0_amount_out)  

    }
```

I'm using `casted_div` function which takes two `u128` objects and turns them into `U256`:

```
    fn casted_div(
        &self,
        value1: u128,
        value2: u128
    ) -> U256 {

        U256::from(value1) / U256::from(value2)

    }
```

Thank you and have a pleasant day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`U256` does implement `TypeInfo`, but it is behind a feature: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/master/primitive-types/src/lib.rs#L40.

Enable the `features = ["scale-info"]" for your primtive-types dependency and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to implement a Trait on a type outside of his crate (Rust oprhan rule).
So the only option is to create a new type that will wrap arround U256 and  derive `TypeInfo`:

```
#[derive(Default, Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Encode, Decode)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub struct WrappedU256(U256);

impl From<WrappedU256> for U256 {
    fn from(value: WrappedU256) -> Self {
        value.0
    }
}

impl From<U256> for WrappedU256 {
    fn from(value: U256) -> Self {
        WrappedU256(value)
    }
}
```